# Python 3.6: Feedparser issue getting sub-attributes

Tags: python, feedparser

I'm using `feedparser` to read in an XML feed which is working fine and I can loop through any level one attributes but I'm unable to access anything thats below level one.

For example I'm unable to pull out any attributes from `links`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```
import feedparser

feed = feedparser.parse("https://dev.test.com/feed.xml")

for post in feed.entries:
    print(post.title) # Works
    print(post.links.rel) # Doesn't work
    print(post.links[0].rel # Doesn't work
```

**Output from post variable**

```
{
    'title': 'test title of article'
    , 'links': [
        {
            'rel': 'alternate'
            , 'type': 'text/html'
            , 'href': 'http://dev.test.com/test-link'
        }
        , {
            'length': '0'
            , 'type': 'image/jpeg'
            , 'href': 'http://dev.test.com/test-link.jpg'
            , 'rel': 'enclosure'
        }
    ]
    , 'link': 'http://dev.test.com/test-link'
    , 'published': 'Tue, 10 Oct 2017 19:21:00 +0100'
}
```

Comment: Could you include the line where you're importing the feedparser module/class?

Comment: @slackmart, added it there.

Comment: A example feed would be nice. And which version of feedparser and python are you using?

Comment: What if you try use `print([link.rel for link in post.links])`?

Comment: Think i got it, I had to use `post.links[0]["rel"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `.rel` and `['rel']` should work:

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> feed = feedparser.parse('https://lwn.net/headlines/newrss')
>>> feed.entries[0].links[0].rel
'alternate'
>>> feed.entries[0].links[0]['rel']
'alternate'
```

As the type of an entry is `FeedParserDict`:

```
>>> type(feed.entries[0].links[0])
<class 'feedparser.FeedParserDict'>
```

Which implements `__getattr__`, see: `help(feed.entries[0].links[0])`.